# Discussion about deleting old unanswered questions of end life releases

Tags: discussion

Is it better to delete the questions that are old and with no answers which belong to end life releases?

Comment: [I'm asking how the rest of SE deals with this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217325/how-should-ask-ubuntu-handle-old-questions-and-answers). It's not just a problem of *what to do* but a question on how we deal with the scale. Thousands and thousands of questions have this problem.

Comment: Its a big problem